# Firefox Add On SDK: How to build a settings page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, xul, jpm

I am building a Firefox Add-On based on the new Mozilla `jpm` Add-On SDK.

**What ist the best way to build a settings or preferences page?**

Should it be made within a new [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel), or a separate [tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs)? Are there any other possibilities?

There are several settings like username, password for an API. 
But there will also be a dashboard presenting data.

AFAIK we should not use XUL to build views anymore. But it is hard to find examples not using XUL. Maybe you know one?

Comment: At least you must forget about XUL. https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/

Comment: yes, but nobody tells us what to do instead :/

Comment: use hidden simple-prefs + tab + html5. this variant will work after migrating to WebExtensions.

Comment: @CoolCmd Thank you! Do you know a link to an example?

Comment: I would register an about page and redirect that about page to your self.data.url. I did that in my addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ try it out, open addons manager, click options, it opens in a new tab

Comment: Noitidart - that's a right nice addon you have there, and the settings file opens right from the addon-manager.  Do you have some blog or page somewhere that elaborates on how to do that?  Or maybe, can you post an answer here to explain?  I glanced through your addon code and it's pretty complex stuff.

Comment: Here is a full explanation of what Noitidart is talking about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#optionsType

Comment: Oops missed your comment, @bgmCoder stackoverflow doesnt inform me unless you call out my name with the @ symbol. Yep thats the MDN page I used to build it, and also its a localized html file which means it has to be xhtml so this simple demo addon explains it - https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul

Answer (score 1):

To only make some values user-accessible, there is the [simple-prefs module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs).

Just declare the variable in your package.json like so

```
"preferences": [{
    "name": "somePreference",
    "title": "Some preference title",
    "description": "Some short description for the preference",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "this is the default string value"
}],
```

and use it like

```
require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['somePreference']
```

Comment: Yeah, but simple prefs are *really ugly*.  Personally, I'd rather build a settings page and use `pagemod` or `panel` to interact with it.

Comment: @bgmCoder: It's an option that's easily accessible, so it should be mentioned as an anwer. Feel free to post one yourself.